# Left Outer Join Using Where to Exclude Records from the Right Table

Tags: sql, t-sql

Using Sql Server 2008. We have a table of jobs done. Normally for any customer, job#1 is followed by job#2 which is followed by job#3.

```
CustNum, JobDate, TypeJob
100,   4/10/2019, 2
100,   4/11/2019, 1
100,   4/12/2019, 2
100,   4/13/2019, 3
100,   4/13/2019, 3
222,   4/10/2019, 2
222,   4/11/2019, 1
333,   4/11/2019, 2
444,   3/1/2019,  3
444,   4/10/2019, 1
444,   4/11/2019, 2
```

I'm looking for all customers which have job#2 with date > job#1 (both existing) but job#3 was not entered afterward.

- Customer 100 is fine with jobs 1,2,3 all completed in sequential date order. I don't want Customer 100.
- Customer 222 doesn't have job#2 after job#1 so I don't want that one either.
- Customer 333 doesn't have any job#1 so I don't want that one.
- Customer 444 is the one I'm looking for.

Here's what I did and it works but it seems clumsy.

```
Select
  L.CustNum, 
  L.JobDate1, 
  L.JobDate2,
  R.JobDate3
From
(
    --A<B has JobDate1 followed by JobDate2
    Select 
      First.CustNum as [CustNum], 
      First.JobDate as JobDate1,
      Second.JobDate as JobDate2
    From
    (
        Select [CustNum], Max([JobDate]) as JobDate From tbJobs
        Where [TypeJob] = 1
        Group by CustNum
    ) First
    Join
    (
        Select [CustNum], Max([JobDate]) as JobDate From tbJobs
        Where [TypeJob] = 2
        Group by CustNum
    ) Second
    On First.CustNum = Second.CustNum
    Where Second.JobDate > First.JobDate
) L
Left Outer Join
(
    --A<B #and# C>A has JobDate1 followed by JobDate2 and JobDate3
    Select 
      First.CustNum as [CustNum], 
      --First.JobDate as JobDate1,
      --Second.JobDate as JobDate2,
      Third.JobDate as JobDate3
    From
    (
        Select [CustNum], Max([JobDate]) as JobDate From tbJobs 
        Where [TypeJob] = 1
        Group by CustNum
    ) First
    Join
    (
        Select [CustNum], Max([JobDate]) as JobDate From tbJobs
        Where [TypeJob] = 2
        Group by CustNum
    ) Second
    On First.CustNum = Second.CustNum
    Join
    (
        Select [CustNum], Max([JobDate]) as JobDate From tbJobs
        Where [TypeJob] = 3
        Group by CustNum
    ) Third
    On Second.CustNum = Third.CustNum
    Where Third.JobDate > First.JobDate
    And Second.JobDate > First.JobDate
) R
On First.CustNum = Third.CustNum
Where JobDate3 is null
Order by CustNum
```

What I really would like to do is something like this:

```
Select ... From
(Select ...) First
Join
(Select ...) Second
Left Outer Join
(Select ...) Third
On ...
Where Second.JobDate > First.JobDate 
    And (Third.JobDate > First.JobDate) is null
```

How would I (is it possible) formulate a Where statement so it ignores any Third.JobDate <= First.JobDate and only finds rows where Third.JobDate (greater than First.JobDate) is null?

Using Sql Server 2008.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple aggregation query should work here:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        CustNum,
        MAX(CASE WHEN TypeJob = 1 THEN JobDate END) AS date1,
        MAX(CASE WHEN TypeJob = 2 THEN JobDate END) AS date2,
        MAX(CASE WHEN TypeJob = 3 THEN JobDate END) AS date3
    FROM tbJobs
    GROUP BY CustNum
)

SELECT CustNum
FROM cte
WHERE
    COALESCE(date2, date1) > COALESCE(date1, date2) AND
    (date3 < date2 OR date3 IS NULL);
```

The use of `COALESCE` in the `HAVING` clause ensures that a customer only passes if he has both the first and second dates present.

Answer (score 0):

Use common table expressions:

```
;WITH First AS (
SELECT CustNum, MAX(JobDate) JobDate1
  FROM tbJobs
 WHERE TypeJob = 1
 GROUP BY CustNum
), Second AS (
SELECT CustNum, MAX(JobDate) JobDate2
  FROM tbJobs
 WHERE TypeJob = 2
 GROUP BY CustNum
), Third AS (
SELECT CustNum, MAX(JobDate) JobDate3
  FROM tbJobs
 WHERE TypeJob = 3
 GROUP BY CustNum
)
SELECT f.CustNum, JobDate1, JobDate2, JobDate3
  FROM First f
 INNER JOIN Second s ON f.CustNum = s.CustNum AND f.JobDate1 < s.JobDate2
  LEFT JOIN Third t ON s.CustNum = t.CustNum AND s.JobDate2 < t.JobDate3
 WHERE JobDate3 IS NULL
```

Comment: This returns no records because `s.JobDate2 < t.JobDate3` returns only rows that are NOT null, but then `WHERE JobDate3 IS NULL` specifies only nulls. So no rows are returned. Doesn't work at all.